# Using SQL PIVOT with JOINS

Tags: sql-server

I have written the following query which produces the output below:

```
SELECT 
users.user_id AS 'User ID', 
users.first_name AS 'First Name', 
users.last_name AS 'Surname', 
users.login AS 'Username', 
CASE users.type WHEN 0 THEN 'Student' WHEN 1 THEN 'Staff Member' WHEN 2 THEN 'Guest / Other' END AS 'User Type', 
CASE users.active WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS 'User Status', campuses.campus_name AS 'Campus', users.year_level AS 'Year Level', 
users.class AS 'Class', 
CASE users.eligible WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Eligible', 
forms.form_title AS 'Form Name', 
users_forms_map.date AS 'Date Returned' 

FROM users_forms_map 
INNER JOIN users ON users_forms_map.user_fk = users.pk 
INNER JOIN campuses ON users.campus_id=campuses.campus_id 
INNER JOIN forms ON users_forms_map.form_id=forms.form_id
```

[image]

I would like to PIVOT this table to create a column for each 'Form Name' and one row per user. The 'Form Name' would need to be dynamic as there is no finite set of form names.

If what I'm hoping to achieve is possible, it would produce the following result:
[image]

I've been struggling to get this right! Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: It would help to see where you have gotten to in terms of an attempt so far.  Please add what you have tried, and how it is failing (error message or wrong output).  Have you successfully used PIVOT before in a simple case, or is this you're first time using it?

Comment: Better done in an application, if possible. Any given query always returns a result set with a fixed shape - the number, name and types of the columns. You could construct a dynamic query but it's going to be ugly and most application programming languages/report builders have better facilities to perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most effective solution was to handle this logic within the application itself. Did not follow through with an server-side SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you ok with executing multiple steps, try like below

```
create table #form
(
userid int,
name varchar(50),
surname varchar(50),
username varchar(50),
type   varchar(50),
userstatus varchar(50),
campus   varchar(50),
level  int ,
class  varchar(1),
eligible varchar(5),
formname varchar(50),
datereturned datetime
)

insert into #form
values
(123, 'thomas', 'pagram', 'tpar2', 'staff member', 'active', 'primary campus',
 0, '', 'yes', 'participation form', '2015-12-29')


insert into #form
values
(123,  'thomas', 'pagram', 'tpar2', 'staff member', 'active', 'primary campus',
 0, '', 'yes', 'one2one contract', '2016-01-01')



 --drop table #form1


 select userid, name, surname, username, type, userstatus, campus, level, class,eligible,
 cast ( '' as date) [participation form] , cast ( '' as date) [one2one contract]
 into #form1
 from #form
 group by userid, name, surname, username, type, userstatus, campus, level, class,eligible


 update f1
 set [participation form] = f.datereturned
 from #form1 f1
 join #form f
 on (f.userid = f1.userid)
 where f.formname = 'participation form'

  update f1
 set [one2one contract] = datereturned
 from #form1 f1
 join #form f
 on (f.userid = f1.userid)
 where f.formname = 'one2one contract'


userid name    surname  username    type            userstatus  campus      level  class       eligible     participation form  one2one contract
123    thomas  pagram   tpar2       staff member    active      primary    campus   0           yes         2015-12-29          2016-01-01
```